# Autofit labels in d3 x-axis

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

I am using ordinal scale for d3 x-axis. If the width of the svg is small, how is the labels suppose to autofit / splice the text automatically so it fits properly in the available spacing not making it cluttered and overlap on each other.

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) should help.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff What if the axis labels are just one big word like [Agfhanistan, Australia, Washington]

Comment: You could rotate them. You could also use the force layout as I've done [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/index-alt.html).

Comment: Just thinking out loud. Doesn't rotating makes it less readable to the user and asks for more attention?

Comment: Yes, but depending on labels/space, it may be the only feasible thing.

Comment: Hmm..Thanks. Atleast i know now that there is no possible alternative until now. Will use the rotating approach only.